# Car insurance covering UK kit car for travel in Italy, France and Spain

Tags: automobiles, insurance

My wife and I are travelling to the UK to collect a car we bought with travel to Italy, France and Spain, for about a year. We both have good clean drivers licenses. I am 71 driving 54 years 1 accident 9 yrs ago, my wife 62 -24 yrs driving no accidents and we are having great trouble getting comprehensive coverage along with roadside assistance. Can anyone help.

Comment: What country are you a resident of?

Comment: It might  be wiser to attempt to get coverage through your present insurer, where your **driving history** is known. Will the bought car be a **left** sided steering Wheel? Driving in Italy and France is difficult at best, but with **right** sided steering wheel will be very confusing.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold for now.